# Can I query data from Room and put it into ViewModel without using Flow?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

dao

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM t_work WHERE id = :id")
fun id(id: Int): Work
```

How should I define a variable in ViewModel to save the data queried from the database?
The reason why Flow is not used is because the data to be queried is very simple, basically the function of the enumeration class. And this data does not need to be mutable, it only needs to be queried once.

```kotlin
// wrong code
class WorkViewModel @Inject constructor(private val workDao: IWorkDao): ViewModel(){
    val work = viewModelScope.async {
        workRepository.ids(listOf(1, 2, 3))
    }.await()
}
```

I don't want to start the coroutine in Compose, which is the view layer, which will increase the complexity of Compose code. Is there an optimal solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can basically start a coroutine in the ViewModel like the following:

```kotlin
class WorkViewModel @Inject constructor(private val workDao: IWorkDao): ViewModel(){
    lateinit var work : Work

    //when view Model is created
    init {
      viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
         work= workDao.id(1)
      }
    }

    // or with a function
    fun updateWork(id : Int){
      viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
         work= workDao.id(id )
      }
    }
}
```

make sure also to update the DAO like the following:

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM t_work WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun id(id: Int): Work
```

That way you can offload the operation to a background dispatcher.

Comment: This doesn't work properly, `lateinit property work has not been initialized`. I first `val workViewModel = hiltViewModel<WorkViewModel>()` in `compose`, and then `val work = workViewModel.work`.

Comment: Well the idea here is just to show you, you can use LiveData or StateFlow to observe that field, and set it within the viewModel. want some code for that?

Comment: Thanks, but no need. I know how to use observable types.